# Cassandra Secondary Index

Tags: indexing, cassandra

Just wanted to learn Cassandra and trying to convert RDBMS design to Canssandra.
Considered my app is being deployed in multiple Data centers.

DB Design :

```
       A) CF : USER
              1) email_id - primary key
              2) fullname
              3) organization - ( I didnt create a separate table for organization )

       B) CF : ORG_USER

             1) organization - Primary Key
             2) email_id

             Here, my intention is to get users belong to an organization.
             Here, I can make the organization in the user table as secondary index, but heard that, this may hit the performance.
             Could you please clarify me which is the better approach?
```

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organization may be a good candidate for a secondary index as long as cardinality is low.  In other words, if you have a lot of repeating values for organization, use a secondary index.  If not, building the index manually (as you have indicated in your ORG_USER CF) is a fine approach.